# Unable to install rJava package in RedHat 5 (R 3.3.0) | Unable to compile a JNI Program

Tags: r

when I am running install.packages("rJava")

Error:-

```
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : ''
java libs   : ''
configure: error: One or more Java configuration variables are not set.
Make sure R is configured with full Java support (including JDK). Run
R CMD javareconf
as root to add Java support to R.

If you don't have root privileges, run
R CMD javareconf -e
to set all Java-related variables and then install rJava.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpyht6l8/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("rJava", "/usr/lib64/R/library", repos = "http://ftp.iitm.ac                                                                                        .in/cran/") :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

---

I ran `R CMD javareconf -e`

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.8.0_91
Java home path   : /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre

Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/../include -I/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/../include/linux -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -ldl -lpthread -lc -lrt -lcurl -lidn -lssh2 -lssl -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -lz -lgssapi -lldap -lz -lrt -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [conftest.so] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program
```

The following Java variables have been exported:

### JAVA_HOME JAVA JAVAC JAVAH JAR JAVA_LIBS JAVA_CPPFLAGS JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Also export JAVA_HOME= jdk_path

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: It looks like as `-lcurl`is missing. Either it isn't installed or not in your PATH. Try `sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev`

Comment: installed -libcurl but still unable to install rJava package. Now error is:
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fpic -fPIC   -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c: In function ‘main’:
conftest.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘JNI_CreateJavaVM’
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program

Answer (score 0):

Install latest java version in your work station and set java home page inside Rstudio, i think it may work

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7")
```